# How to check main reason for crash in crash report shared by app store

Tags: ios, app-store, crash-reports, appstore-approval, app-store-connect

I got these crash report from apple for one of my app. But am not sure what exactly they want to address. How can i figure out the reason from crash report. So, i can resolve the crash if it exists. Am not able to reproduce any crash.

```
Date/Time:           2019-09-26 11:57:38.1059 -0700
Launch Time:         2019-09-26 11:57:17.9594 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.4.1 (16G102)
Baseband Version:    7.80.04
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: MY_APP_NAME exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 17.92 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 30.440 (user 30.440, system 0.000), 51% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.520, 1% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
```

Comment: something is taking too much time collapsing main thread completly! as you can read in `Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: MY_APP_NAME exhausted real (wall clock),`

Comment: Thanks @ReinierMelian but am not able to reproduce the crash, Is there any way i can replicate the same. It will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: MY_APP_NAME exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 17.92 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 30.440 (user 30.440, system 0.000), 51% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.520, 1% CPU" | )
```

clearly suggests you have a timeout. Time allowance is of 17.92 seconds.

Comment: How can I find the task whose responsible for this

Comment: @AbhiYaduwanshi we know that the crash happened in com.apple.main-thread and you might want to log any potentially longer method running in the main-thread. Then check the logs just after the crash to see what was running then.

Comment: Thanks @Lajos but Am trying hard to reproduce, but not able to reproduce the crash, Is there any way i can replicate the same?

Comment: @AbhiYaduwanshi if you deploy the logging, then at the time when the crash is reproduced, you will be able to see what was running at the time. I understand that it's difficult to reproduce, but we cannot find the information unless it's available. Check your logs to see whether any helpful clue is there. If not, then I think you have nothing better than deploying support for finding out what the issue is and then wait for the issue to be reproduced, maybe actively trying to do so.